# Find the competitive equilibrium of the following economy

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, general-equilibrium, competitive-equilibrium

The following question was given as a part of a task in microeconomic theory course. It is not from some textbook and since I still haven't figured a way to solve it I will leave it here. Thank you in advance.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{+}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be a single output production function such that

$$f(z_1, z_2) = (z_1^\delta+z_2^\delta)^{\frac{1}{\delta}},\quad \text{with $0<\delta<1$}$$

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^3$ be the consumption set. The vector of commodities $(z_1, z_2, q)$ is a typical element of $X$. There are $N=\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ individuals (with $n\geq 2$) where the typical individual is denoted by $i$. Each $i$ has a preference relation $\succsim_i$ defined over $X$ and the utility representation of $\succsim_i$ is given by $u_i(z_1, z_2, q) = i(z_1+z_2) +q$. Individual $1$ owns the technology, but has an endowment $\mathcal{E}_1 =(0, 0, 0)$. For every $i\in N-\{1\}$ and some pair of non-negative real numbers $a_1$, $a_2$, $\mathcal{E}_i =(\frac{a_1}{n-1}, \frac{a_2}{n-1}, 0)$.

Which is the competitive (Arrow-Debreu) equilibrium for this economy?

I believe it will be easier if we set $n=2$ to solve the problem.

Comment: Should it be $X=\mathbb{R}^3_+$, or is negative consumption really allowed here?

Comment: As it is given, it is $X = \mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 3):

There will be no equilibrium. Both technology and endowment play no role in the argument.

Assume there would be an equilibrium with price system $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$.

Notice that all prices must be strictly positive since all goods are desirable.

The optimality condition of agent $1$ implies that $p_1=p_3$. If, say, $p_1<p_3$, agent $1$ could always improve by consuming one unit less of good $3$ and consuming $p_3/p_1$ units more of good $1$. Since negative consumption is allowed, this would always be feasible and an improvement.

Similarly, we must have $p_1=2 p_3$. Otherwise, agent $2$ could improve.

All in all, we get $0<p_1=2p_3=2p_1$, which is clearly absurd.

Comment: Sorry.... I don't follow...you write price system $(p_1, p_2, p_2)$ and you say optimality condition of agent $1$ is $p_1=p_3$.... and what do you mean by optimality condition? Please, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: If a bundle is preferred by an agent to what they consume, it must cost more. That is all I am using here. If it helps you, you can also argue that equality of marginal rates of substitution is necessary here since there are boundary constraints.

Comment: If the production function technology and the endownement are just irrelevant then...why de we need them in frist place? I begin to understand your answer. But in case $X=\mathbb{R}_{+}^3$, then would that change the outcome? I am asking that because you mentioned this in the beginning

Comment: Yes, that would change things a lot. That's why I asked.

Comment: Ok then, could we consider both cases? Cause maybe it  is a typo...not mine...the professor's :P

Comment: You could start by solving the profit maximization problem.

Comment: I can not understand how to write downt the profit maximization problem. You have for agent $1$

$$max_{q}\quad \left(p \underbrace{f(z)}_{q}- c(p_1,p_2, q)\right)$$ and for any other $i\in N-\{1\}$ $$max_{x_{1i},x_{2,i}}\quad\left( u_i(x_{1i},x_{2,i})\right)\quad \text{s.t $p\mathcal{E}_i=p_1x_{1,i}+p_2x_{2,i}$}$$?

Comment: The firm maximizes profit. Who owns it is irrelevant at that stage. This is just tedious undergraduate microeconomics.

Comment: I can not understand that....if it is irrelevant why is it mentioned? You mean that it does not matter since there is one player who plays the firm and another who plays the consumer?

Comment: One last question. You write ``Assume there would be an equilibrium with price system $(p_1,p_2,p_2)$. " Do you mean $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$?

Comment: Profit maximization has nothing to do with ownership structure. The firm maximizes profit. Agent 1 consumes. Their income is the firm's profit, but the decisions are made separately. And yes, it should be $p_3$.

Comment: Below I posted a possible answer...I do not know if it is could be correct...Glad to discuss it, but this is my effort about this one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the economy has two agents, $n=2$ and since individual $1$ owns the production, this means that the firm belongs to agent $1$ who has no endowment.

Suppose that the firm produces the commodity good $q$ by using as inputs the commodities $z_1$ and $z_2$. Then the problem of agent $1$ is

$$\text{max}_{(z_1,z_2,q)}\{z_1+z_2+q\},\quad\text{s.t. $p_1z_1+p_2z_2+p_3q\leq \pi_f$}$$

Where $\pi_f = p_3f(z_1,z_2)-(p_1z_2+p_2z_2)$ is the profit function and $f(z_1,z_2)=q$

Also the problem of agent $2$ is

$$\text{max}_{(z_1,z_2,q)}\{2(z_1+z_2)+q\},\quad\text{s.t. $p_1z_1+p_2z_2+p_3q\leq p_1\alpha_1+p_2\alpha_2$}$$

By solving the lagrangian for agent $1$ and agent $2$, we have that $p_1=p_2=p_3$ and $p_1=p_2=2p_3$ respectively. The only vector of prices that satisfies both of the latter conditions about the prices is $(p_1, p_2, p_3) = (0,0,0)$

Then (either) there is not an equilibrium for this economy, because prices must be non-negative and at least some of them strictly positive.

Or else the only equilibrium that satisfy the given economy is the one that implies a zero profit condition (which I am not sure if this is just equivalent to the fact that $(p_1, p_2, p_3) = (0,0,0)$)

Comment: Using the same variables for both agents' consumptions and the firm's inputs is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, but it saves time to the paper in order to solve the problem :P Do you want me to change the notation?

Comment: It does ignore the firm's problem. If you want to try the case in which consumptions have to be nonnegative too, this needs to be done.

Comment: yes, the firms problem does not play much of a role. Do I miss a case?

Comment: The demand of the consumers will look different if nonnegativity constraints bind and then the actual amount of profit can matter.

Comment: I  am a bit confused....is there any other case that I need to consider?

Comment: If you require consumption to be nonnegative, yes. In  that case you can get different demand.

Comment: If negative consumption is assumed, then we have that $z_1<0$, $z_2<0$ and $q<0$. But in any case the results remains unchanged. If this is that you mean...

Comment: If you require demand to be nonnegative, I'm pretty sure that an equilibrium exists.

Comment: No it doesn't. The problems written above do not change the result. If you take cases for example, $z_1>0$ and $z_2=0$, then you will have $p_1=p_3$ and $p_1=2p_3$ and thus $p_1=p_3=0$. Also,  if $z_1=0$, $z_2>0$ , then you will have $p_2=p_3$ and $p_2=2p_3$ and thus $p_2=p_3=0$. Am I thinking wrong? If you think I am mistaken feel free to give a solution, i can not think of anyone...

Comment: I have no idea what you are writing here. What is the argument for these equalities?

Comment: The first order conditions of the agents problems. Take the problems and make the calculations, these are going to be the results

Comment: The prices are fixed for the utility maximization problem; they are not the outcome of the maximization problem. If you allow for negative consumption, these equalities need to be satisfied for any solution to exist. If consumption needs to be nonnegative, a utility-maximizing consumption plan will always exist as long as all prices are positive.   Here is a simple example: Let $p_1=1, p_2=2, p_3=3, a_1=a_3=1$. The demand of agent 1 is (m,0,0) with $m$ the income, and the demand of agent 2 is $(3,0,0)$. Everything is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I understand your point, but under this specific setting there is no other case here. Or at least, I can not see another solution. For this economy there is not equilibrium, if there is and someone can find it, then I would appreciate to see a solution. Thank you in advance